# Qemu switches to "stopped" state during bootup

Tags: virtualization, qemu

I recently tried to boot up my image of Debian and noticed that during bootup, Qemu - according to the window title - switches it state to QEMU [stopped] and doesn't respond. I checked `qemu-kvm` and `qemu-system-i386`/`qemu-system-x86_64` and it stopped at different moments, but never booted up completely. I know that the machine worked fine before. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I found out on #qemu on irc.oftc.net IRC channel:

> 20:07:59    mjt $ d33tah: df on the host
>
> 20:35:52   iggy $ d33tah: is your host drive out of space?

This is because the host's hard drive ran out of space. Free up disk space and the machine should start working again.

Answer (score 4):

QEMU switches to stopped on two occasions - EIO (read/write error) or ENOSPACE (out of space error). You should see either in the logs and act accordingly

Comment: And if there is plenty of space than what?

Comment: If it's not ENOSPACE then it's EIO, check why qemu could not read or write to the location where the VM image resides.

Comment: If the problem is indeed "no space", then after you've cleaned the filesystem to get some space, to resume QEMU do: 1. Switch to its console via `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`2`, 2. Type `cont` and press `Return` key, 3. Switch back to the user screen via `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`1`.

Comment: Doing Ctrl + Alt + 2 just opens a screen that says "parallel0 console" and also says [Stopped] in the title bar